# Monitor displays light shadows

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I recently bought a second-hand monitor, same model as my first monitor, in order to get dual-display with the same monitor each time.

This second-hand monitor has an issue however : all pixels displayed are displayed again in a lighter shade on the right. You should be able to see the shadow of my black line as a gray line of the same thickness on this picture.

(This is a picture of a black line on white background.)

It doesn't seem to be related to any hardware outside the monitor itself, since I swapped the monitor with its older brother, which did not display the symptoms.

Is this a common issue in monitors, and is it fixable ?

[image]

Comment: What kind of connection are you using between the monitor and computer?  VGA, DVI, HDMI?  If it is VGA especially try using either a DVI or HDMI connection to test and see if that resolves the issue.  Some VGA cables themselves can be the culprit, you can have a "bad" cable, so try a different one of those too if that is what you are using.

Comment: Unfortunately, my monitors only have VGA input ports. I believed I previously checked whether the issue appeared with another cable and concluded that only the monitor could be the source. I'll check again.

Comment: Yeah, the higher the resolution the more issues you have with VGA.  It is really an *old* standard.  However, if you are using another identical monitor and the same resolution and that one is VGA then the cable is the next thing to test.  Use the cable from the known "good" monitor and if you still see the artifact on the "bad" monitor then you can say it is not the cable and likely the monitor itself.

Comment: I have to say that you were entirely correct. I switched my monitors on their VGA cables and the other monitor received the same issue. I had not noticed this previously, because the issue only shows at higher resolutions (1600x900). Would you like to formulate your answer so i can select it ?

Comment: Right on, glad the root of the issue is solved now.  Made a write-up as you requested. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the VGA cable, as indicated.  VGA cables can develop defects over time and that may result in different cables working either correctly or incorrectly.  Some VGA cables are just "bad."  Swapping it out with a different, especially "known to be good" cable is the first trouble-shooting step to try.

Comment: Actually, I had the problem twice with both times new VGA cables. This is what let me to believe that the VGA cables were not the issue... but they were ! Thanks again :)

Comment: Right on, you're welcome. :)